# Как выполнить sql запрос?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT w.name_worker, w.surname_worker, w.midname_worker, w.id_worker, SUM(number) numb
FROM workers w 
    LEFT JOIN exhours e ON (w.id_worker = e.id_worker) 
    LEFT JOIN orders o ON (e.id_order = o.id_order)
WHERE o.datetime_order >= '$date_start' AND o.datetime_order <= '$date_end' 
GROUP BY w.id_worker
```

Использую такой запрос, чтобы посчитать количество отработанных часов сотрудником за период времени.
Как можно добавить в выдачу всех сотрудников из таблицы `workers`, чтобы были и те, кто ничего не отработал за этот период?
Посоветовали использовать `left join`, но у меня ничего не поменялось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если есть **WHERE**, то его условие в запросе является обязательным, следовательно у пользователей которые ничего не отработали, вероятно записей в таблице orders нет, поэтому ваше условие отсекает таких.

Вам нужно вынести это условие в JOIN и тогда появятся сотрудники которые ничего не отработали в этом периоде.

```
SELECT w.name_worker,
       w.surname_worker,
       w.midname_worker,
       w.id_worker,
       SUM(number) numb
FROM workers w
LEFT JOIN exhours e ON (w.id_worker = e.id_worker)
LEFT JOIN orders o ON (e.id_order = o.id_order
                       AND o.datetime_order >= $date_start
                       AND o.datetime_order <= $date_end)
GROUP BY w.id_worker
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. А можете подсказать еще и в похожем моменте. Я сейчас создам другую тему